# While converting a function to MySQLi, I get an 'Undefined index' error

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm changing my `mysql` functions to `mysqli` ones and have come across an interesting problem.

I want to echo out specific user data. I created a function where I insert multiple arguments (each argument represents a column in the database) and then echo whichever column I want with a simple line of code.

My code below will further explain it if what I just said was confusing. It is in it's entirety.

My problem is is that it is not working.

It's returning an error that says, `Notice: Undefined index: last_name in...` which occurs on the very last line of code, `echo $user_data['last_name'];`.

What is causing the error? Is it the function? If so, where is the problem? This is my first day working with `mysqli`.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

Here is the function:

```
function user_data ($mysqli, $user_id) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();
    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);
        unset($func_get_args[1]);
        $fields ='`' .  implode ('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        //here I am starting the mysqli prepared statement              
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ? FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('si', $fields, $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            //here I am trying to convert the result into an array
            $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
            while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
                $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
            }
            call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                foreach($row as $key => $val) {
                        $x[$key] = $val;
                }
                $results[] = $x;
            }
            return $results;
            $stmt->close(); 
            }
    }
}
```

Testing out the function to see if it works:

```
$session_user_id = 1;
$user_data = user_data($mysqli, $session_user_id, 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email');
echo $user_data['last_name'];
```

A `var_dump()` for the variable `$user_data` returns with this.

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["?"]=> string(58) "`username`, `password`, `first_name`, 
`last_name`, `email`" } }
```

Comment: You can't use `?` in `prepare` for a table or column name. [See the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-parameters).

Comment: Would that then make the purpose of prepared statements invalid since I'm not injecting any data into the database, and simply just calling it?

Comment: Prepared statements are good, but you might want to create an array like `$valid = array('username', 'password', ...);`, then check the input with `in_array`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `?` in `prepare` for a table or column name. [See the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-parameters).

Instead, create an array like

```
$valid = array('username', 'password', ...);
```

then check the input with [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$fields = array();
foreach($func_get_args as $arg) {
    if(in_array($arg, $valid)) $fields[] = $arg;
}
$fields = '`' . implode ('`, `', $fields) . '`';
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?")) {
    // ...
```

Comment: If I follow the former instructions I receive Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''user_id'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING and if I follow with the latter I receive Notice: Undefined index: last_name. This function worked before with mysql, so I know that user_data can accept more arguments even if it appears it only accepts two

Comment: @jason328 Okay, what line? You have got two single quotes on each side of `user_id` somewhere.

Comment: For the former, the error is caught on the first line that creates the function `function user_data($mysqli, $user_id, 'username'...` and for the latter, when I echo out 'lastname' with `echo $user_data['last_name'];`

Comment: @jason328 Somewhere in your code that you haven't posted, the is something like `$user = $user_data[''user_id''];`. It should be `$user = $user_data['user_id'];`.

Comment: What's in the question is my code in its entirety. There are is no other calls with `$user_data['some_column']` except for the very last line of code seen in my question.

Comment: @jason328 - **What line did the error occur on?** And what line of code is on that line?

Comment: The original error stated in the question occurs on the very last line of the code, `echo $user_data['last_name'];`

Comment: @jason328 Sorry, it just clicked. Replace the `echo` with this (for debugging): `var_dump($user_data);`. What does that output?

Comment: response is now in question. Not what I expected because it should return data specific to the user_id of 1 as per requested in the variable `$session_user_id`.